# Django 2.1.1 don't find Module pytz

Tags: python-3.x, apache, virtualenv

I am trying to deploy a new Django application on an apache web server. The wsgi configuration works fine. However, when ever I try to open the application I run  into an internal server error. The log says:

**django/utils/timezone.py**

**import pytz**

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'**

However, when I do:

```
python
import pytz
print(pytz.__version__)
```

everything works fine.

Any ideas ?

///Edit:
Forgot to mention that I am using python3.6 and Django2.1.1

Answer (score -1):

Try to add pytz in your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py and in your requirements.txt.